# how to solve C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

when i want to get dependencies i recieved this error

i tried to fix with put path into enviroment variables but it didn`t work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
>
> C:\Windows\System32

to your PATH variable

Do not create new variable for git but add them as I did one after another separating them by `;`

Remember to restart `terminal/vscode` after changing `environment variables`.

Comment: Assuming you actually have git installed and it resides at that location.